# How can I display directories in the "Recent" folder?

Tags: nautilus

"Recent" folder in Nautilus only displays recent **files**.

[image: recent nautilus]

Can it display recent **folders** too, such as in the "save as" interface?

[image: save as]

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the folders in which Recently Used Files reside, or are you just looking for Recently Accessed folders?

(Note that, Recently Accessed folders are listed on the Unity Dash "Home" scope, under "Files and Folders").

If you follow the premise that a folder will be considered to have been Recently Accessed, if a file *within* the folder was recently used, then you can see all folders for recently used files...

1. Click on "Recent" in the Nautilus left pane, under "Places".
2. Click on the "View items as a list" button at the top right of Nautilus.  (It is the button icon with three bars).
3. Right click on the column header bar ("Name", "Type", "Size", "Modified") in the files pane of Nautilus.
4. Then select elect "Location" from the pop-up menu. This will add an extra Location column to the display.

Comment: I mean recently accessed folder. The Dash solution does not allow to open a new tab into the same nautilus windows.
Good solution for the other case!

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. <kbd>Right-click</kbd> on the file in *Recent files*.
2. Then click *Visit file*.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version does *Visit file* exist on? Because on Ubuntu 22.04 I can see that the option is named *Open Item Location*.

Comment: This with Ubuntu 22.04 -  language and Region -> English (United Kingdom)